# preventing an inline script from running

Tags: javascript

The login for a public web site contains the following (in the main page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input[type=text]').bind('cut copy paste', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
  });
  $('input[type=password]').bind('cut copy paste', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>
```

Since I use 32-character random passwords (that, on a good day, I can type correctly maybe one time in three), I obviously prefer to paste the password in from my password manager.

I found an extension that will allegedly overcome this, but I want to know if some way exists in the developer tools (or maybe using userscripts) to prevent this snippet from running. Note that I have fairly marginal programming skills, and minimal experience using developer tools in a browser, so more details will help. :)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: They're using jQuery, so removing those handlers should be really simple, just `.off`

Comment: if you don't want that functionality on the site, why not just remove the script?

Comment: I tried removing the element, but (if I understand) the script gets executed on load, and simply removing the element in developer tools doesn't work.

Comment: I read the referred question, but don't know where to put `.off`. Can you provide a modified code snippet? Thanks.